# Send function calls with different arguments to different processors in R using parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use the parallel package in R to send four different function calls to four different processors but am really lost as to how to assign different cores to do different work.  I've read through the documentation for the parallel package, doParallel, Rmpi, and foreach in R.  I've seen many posts using mclapply for calling different functions with the same argument.  I'd like to call the same function with different arguments.

This is pseudocode of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
BEGIN parallel (core)
if(core == 1)
   foo(5, 4, 1/2, 3, "a")
if(core == 2)
   foo(5, 3, 1/3, 1, "b")
if(core == 3)
   foo(5, 4, 1/4, 1, "c")
if(core == 4)
   foo(5, 2, 1/5, 0, "d")
END parallel
```

This seems to be a perfect application to parallel computing since these four separate function calls can act independently to solve the problem I am working on.  I don't know how to do this in R though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

Step 0: Setting up the cluster & user data

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(4)          # Assuming 4 node cluster
registerDoParallel(cl) 

foo <- function(...) paste(...,collapse="-") # A dummy function:

(parDf <- data.frame(x1=5,x2=c(4,3,4,2),x3=1/(2:5),x4=3:0,x5=letters[1:4])) # Dummy parameters
parDf$x5 <- as.character(parDf$x5)
```

Step 1: Find process id of each node:

```
nodeNames <- foreach(i = 1:length(cl), .combine=c) %dopar% {
  Sys.getpid()
}
```

Step 2: Use the process id to choose a specific set of parameters:

```
foreach(i = 1:10, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  paste(Sys.getpid(),foo(parDf[which(Sys.getpid()==nodeNames),]))
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, Shambho.  When I try this code with my foo function, I receive an error that the second parameter in my function is missing.

Comment: Hmm... Plz share your foo function.

Comment: My script of your suggestion and my foo are available at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwgtugt8dwddhqx/gbProbPar_ToShow2.R).  I modified some of the inputs since my original post and changed the name of my foo function.

Comment: Please write the function here, or share it in an open google doc. I don't download files.

Comment: My apologies.  You can view the code in the open Google Doc at this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rru_NYrIVkFfjPKvgZV65yigJOyUfWn5Sp4pSqeOVBo/pub).  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with your recurComp function! You need to fix that.

Comment: Try: `recurComp(4,4,.04,2,"GG")`

Comment: It appears my question is more on declaring arrays inside a recursive function.  I am aware that parallel programs in R cannot access global variables so I tried to use `!exists()` commands at the beginning of `recurComp` to see if my four arrays had been initialized yet. If they hadn't, I wanted to created them there and then have the recursive function fill them.  The `recurComp(4, 4, .04, 2, "GG")` command you requested works in serial, but only if I declare GG, GW, etc. as global variables. I want to declare 4 arrays in a recursive function, fill them simultaneously, & return the results.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But you see that is a separate question, and you should ask it as a new question with appropriate name and details. This question, I think, I have already answered.

Comment: Hope you got your question answered!!

Comment: I did.  Thanks for your help with this one!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the clusterApply function from the parallel package:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, "foo")
cores <- seq_along(cl)
r <- clusterApply(cl[cores], cores, function(core) {
  if (core == 1) {
    foo(5, 4, 1/2, 3, "a")
  } else if (core == 2) {
    foo(5, 3, 1/3, 1, "b")
  } else if (core == 3) {
    foo(5, 4, 1/4, 1, "c")
  } else if (core == 4) {
    foo(5, 2, 1/5, 0, "d")
  }
})
```

This is very similar to your pseudocode and demonstrates how you can direct particular tasks to particular cluster workers using clusterApply. Note that by changing the value of `cores`, you can execute on any subset of the cluster workers that you choose.

If a "core ID" isn't really important, you can pass different arguments to the function by iterating over vectors for each of the arguments using the foreach package:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl)
r2 <- foreach(a1=c(5,5,5,5), a2=c(4,3,4,2), a3=c(1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5),
              a4=c(3,1,1,0), a5=c("a","b","c","d")) %dopar% {
  foo(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  "a" corresponds to an array named a that is declared outside of the function I am calling.  When I try the first clusterApply code, it says that the a array cannot be found.

Comment: I really like the way that the doParallel option looks and it is similar to what I tried previously.  The code works perfectly if I change %dopar% to %do%, but %dopar% appears to not even call the function as each of the input arrays a, b, c, and d remain in their initialized form.  I've tried to print() some values in the foo function to see if it is getting in there with %dopar% but it doesn't spit anything out.

Comment: @compstatguy It sounds like a variable export problem. foo is probably being called with %dopar%, but output from workers is thrown away by the workers unless you use the makeCluster "outfile" option. If you include an example that demonstrates the problem then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: My R script is available at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vczd4ak70o4hmme/gbProbPar_ToShow.R).  I have not used the outfile option so it appears that the work is being thrown away as you suggested.  I've also included the code for your first suggestion but it is commented out in the file.  Thanks!

Comment: @compstatguy Since your function reads the global variables GG, GW, WG, and WW, you need to export them using `clusterExport(cl, c('GG', 'GW', 'WG', 'WW'))`. But unfortunately it also modifies them, which is almost always a big problem for parallel programs. I think you're going to have to rewrite the function to not modify any global variables to get it to work in parallel.

Comment: I modified my code so that GG, GW, WG, and WW are all declared inside my function and are not global variables anymore. The code continues to give the correct result when %do% is selected, but when I use %dopar% it gives the following error before I get to the clusterExport you suggested:  `Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'GG' not found"`. I have tried to both declare the arrays as global and not and it always gives this same error.

Comment: I've found that this error goes back to the use of `<<-` which I had to use when I was modifying the global arrays. That doesn't work when I am modifying arrays declared in my function. The trouble now is that when I change this to `<-` for assigning a new value after updating `prob` in the recursion, all of the other values in the array are lost except for the one I am currently trying to overwrite. Ideally, I would like to be able to place the vectors I am filling into the output of the `foreach` command that does the parallelization but the recursive calls are turning these all into N/A's.